# How to retrieve data in vuejs from laravel eloquent?

Tags: vue.js, eloquent, laravel-8

By using relationship one to one in laravel eloquent I can get data from table users and countries.

In User model

```
public function country(){
   return $this->hasOne(App\Models\Country::class,'id','id_country');
}
```

In blade template, to get the name of the country I can get it like this.

```
$user = App\Models\User::all()
$user_native = $user->country->name
```

Using the same result, how can I retrieve the country name in vue.js? Let's say that the returned data are in `user` so to call user's name I can do `@{{ user.name }}`. But when I tried to get country name using `@{{ user.country.name }}`, I get error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`.

Comment: You can either create an API to your backend (recommended) or add the value directly as a JavaScript variable into the page ([`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Comment: Of course I use API to get all data. For now, I use left join instead of hasOne. It solve the problem but still I'm wondering if I can use hasOne eloquent